# Content pushed down page when nav bar height is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a question, and I can't seem to figure it out. I have a button that when it is clicked the navigation bar should extend all the way to the bottom of the screen and take up all of the other content, or in other words, the page should not be scrollable. Instead, the navigation bar takes up 100% of the screen but when I scroll I can still see the content below and do not know why. Here is my code so far...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-nav">
    <nav id="nav">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><button onclick="expandNav()"><i class="fal fa-bars"></i></button></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-connectdevelop"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Moderator</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">

  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function expandNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.height = "100vh";
  }
</script>
```

As you can see when the button is clicked the nav bar's height is set to 100vh to take up the entire page.

Here is my CSS code...

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.top-nav .nav-bar {
  width: 82%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

/* START -- Disabling resizing affects*/



/* END -- Disabling resizing affets*/

.top-nav nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  height: 44px;
  background: #040406;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.top-nav nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;

  height: 44px;

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-nav nav a {
  display: inline;

  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.top-nav ul li:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(2) i {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(2):hover a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.top-nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #939393;
}

.top-navul li:nth-child(2):hover a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(9) i, ul li:last-child i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-content {
  height: calc(100vh - 44px);
  width: 100%;
  background:   #131218;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* START -- Top Navigation Bar */
  .top-nav .nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .top-nav ul li:first-child{
    display: flex;
  }

  .top-nav button i {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .top-nav ul li:hover button i {
    color: #939393;
  }

  .top-nav ul button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .top-nav ul li:first-child button {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
  }

  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(2) i {
    color: dodgerblue;
  }

  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(3), .top-nav ul li:nth-child(4), .top-nav ul li:nth-child(5), .top-nav ul li:nth-child(6), .top-nav ul li:nth-child(7), .top-nav ul li:nth-child(8), .top-nav ul li:nth-child(9), .top-nav ul li:nth-child(10) {
    display: none;
  }
  /* END -- Top Navigation Bar */
}
```

**To summarize:** When I set my nav bar to 100vh it takes up the entire page, but when I scroll all the content below it is pushed down and I do not want that, I simply want it to take up the entire page. If you do not understand what I am asking, you can go to Apple's website, resize the window (on the x-axis) and click the menu on the top left of the page. You will see how it takes up the entire page.

Here is a screenshot of what I have now:

[image]

The bottom part (the different color) is the content that I have yet to put on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` on body when applying 100vh height on the navbar

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
```

```js
function expandNav() {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow === "hidden") {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.height = "";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.height = "100vh";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.top-nav .nav-bar {
  width: 82%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}


/* START -- Disabling resizing affects*/


/* END -- Disabling resizing affets*/

.top-nav nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 44px;
  background: #040406;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.top-nav nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-nav nav a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.top-nav ul li:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(2) i {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(2):hover a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.top-nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #939393;
}

.top-navul li:nth-child(2):hover a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(9) i,
ul li:last-child i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-content {
  height: calc(100vh - 44px);
  width: 100%;
  background: #131218;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* START -- Top Navigation Bar */
  .top-nav .nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:first-child {
    display: flex;
  }
  .top-nav button i {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:hover button i {
    color: #939393;
  }
  .top-nav ul button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:first-child button {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(2) i {
    color: dodgerblue;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(3),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(4),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(5),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(6),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(7),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(8),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(9),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(10) {
    display: none;
  }
  /* END -- Top Navigation Bar */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eed659c9d4.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-nav">
    <nav id="nav">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><button onclick="expandNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-connectdevelop"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Moderator</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">

  </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

**2nd snippet** for solution to problem asked in comments

```js
function expandNav() {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.contains("openNavbar")) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove("openNavbar");
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add("openNavbar");
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.top-nav .nav-bar {
  width: 82%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}


/* START -- Disabling resizing affects*/


/* END -- Disabling resizing affets*/

.top-nav nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 44px;
  background: #040406;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.top-nav nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-nav nav a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.top-nav ul li:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(2) i {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(2):hover a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.top-nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #939393;
}

.top-navul li:nth-child(2):hover a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.top-nav ul li:nth-child(9) i,
ul li:last-child i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-content {
  height: calc(100vh - 44px);
  width: 100%;
  background: #131218;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* START -- Top Navigation Bar */
  .top-nav .nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:first-child {
    display: flex;
  }
  .top-nav button i {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:hover button i {
    color: #939393;
  }
  .top-nav ul button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:first-child button {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(2) i {
    color: dodgerblue;
  }
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(3),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(4),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(5),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(6),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(7),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(8),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(9),
  .top-nav ul li:nth-child(10) {
    display: none;
  }
  /* END -- Top Navigation Bar */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body.openNavbar {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  body.openNavbar #nav {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eed659c9d4.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-nav">
    <nav id="nav">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><button onclick="expandNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-connectdevelop"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Moderator</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">

  </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I don't understand the else statement that you have used. What is that for? Finally, what is the use of using getElementsByTagName("body")[0] this? Thank you so much for your answer again!

Comment: I used that else to give toggling effect for the navbar, if you click the bars icons again :) You can ignore it if you dont want it.

Comment: What toggling effect? :) When I add the else statement nothing happens for some reason. Edit: Opps, never mind. Just saw it, thank you so much again! :) I will accept this answer when it lets me (in 2 minutes) :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I don't understand what this line of code does document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = ""; What is there no value assigned in the quotes?  And when you use [0] are you referring to the first child of the body tag? Thanks! :)

Comment: When we use document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "", it removes any overflow style applied as inline on the body tag. Also getElementsByTagName returns an aray of elements, but we know that there is only 1 body element so we cans safely use 0th ([0])index to refer to that body element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176205/discussion-between-omar-dajani-and-nandita-arora-sharma).